# How to hook several div to hover?

Tags: jquery

How can I hook several divs to hover? I use `add()` but its not working.

```
var h1 = $('.a');
var h2 = $('.b');
var h3 = $('.c');
var all = h1.add(h2).add(h3);

all.stop(true, true).hover(function(){// not work
    var this_id = $(this).filter('.a').attr('id');
    // do something
}, function(){
    ...
});
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?  Does anything happen?  Worst case, you could always combine your selectors into one... `var all = $('.a, .b, .c');`  I realize that may not be an option, just a suggestion.

Comment: only `.a` be hook, no errors in console

Comment: @vibskov This works  http://jsfiddle.net/KptWA/ See the console log in the fiddle

Comment: Have you verified that .b and .c match any elements?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that code, my entire JS page will be executed before your code...

Comment: I get it, because var this_id = $(this).filter('.a').attr('id'); should change to $(this).attr('id') Thanks for all reply!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate using `,`

```
$('.a, .b, .c').hover(function(){
  ......
});
```

or

```
 var all = $('.a, .b, .c');

 $(all).hover(function(){
  ......
});
```

Comment: @OP, you could also use - var all = $('.a, .b, .c');

Answer (score 2):

you can do

```
$('.a, .b, .c').hover()
```

Answer (score 0):

I get it, because `var this_id = $(this).filter('.a').attr('id');` should change to `$(this).attr('id')`
Thanks for all answer let me sure add() is working!!!